# MySQL-PHP - Update column value every day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named 'periodo' with INTEGER values representing the days left to realize some work.
So I need to decrease 1 to column 'periodo' every day so the notice will be ie. "You have 4 days left", the next day "You have 3 days left" and so on.
I know this can be done with events in MySQL but the thing is if MySQL server is down for 2 days for example on weekends, the field wont be updated, and when it's open again the event wouldn't exist (thats what I think, I have little experience with events)-

So I figured this out, I have another column with the date of the beginning of that work (fecha_entrega), plus the 'periodo' column I can use DATEDIFF() every time the index.php page is loaded in this way:

```
UPDATE compromisos SET periodo = periodo - SELECT DATEDIFF('CURDATE()','fecha_entrega');
```

but I think that its a weird and inefficient way to do what I want.

Help me choosing the most efficient way to do what I want whereas the server could be down sometimes please!

Comment: Store the end date instead. And just calculate number of days instead. Much better than every day update periodo

Comment: Instead of updating the column, why don't you use an end_date column, and calculate days left between today's date and end_date?

Comment: @wizKid +1 Days left would be an arbitrary value. End date is absolute and you don't deal with the potential to lose the data as easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing the end date in mysql and also storing it in memcached for some time period as a backup for when your mysql server is down since you wouldn't be able to query the db. Then of course calculate the remaining time.

Comment: Why I had not thought of that? That's so simple, thanks!

Comment: I'd like to upvote but I need 15 reputation in order to upvote and someone gave me a downvote in this question :( but I promise when I get 15 reputation I'll give you the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the begin date of the work and the remaining time / days, store the deadline date. Then, you can always count the remaining time to complete the work (or it is overdue).